# Performance measurement for VoltDB RDBMS

Tags: voltdb

I want to measure the performance of **VoltDB RDBMS** against TPCC queries. I have tried some VoltDB system procedures like **@Statistics**, @SystemCatalog, but I am looking for **CPU and memory utilization percentage**.

Where do I get these performance details?  Though @Statistics gives CPU utilization, it is in integer form. Can I measure it in float format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out, @Statistics CPU provides the CPU utilization % as an integer.  VoltDB doesn't have any other way to provide this.  You might use some linux command-line tools such as top or mpstat if you are looking for something with more precision.

The memory utilization is reported by the RSS number in @Statistics MEMORY.  You can also track this directly using Linux tools.

You may find the [Benchmarking chapter](https://docs.voltdb.com/PlanningGuide/ChapBenchmark.php) in the Planning Guide useful, as well as the first 4 chapters of the [Guide to Performance and Customization](https://docs.voltdb.com/PerfGuide/).